# Trouble with Swift's "Bridging-Header.h"

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

For some of my OBJc class header files, I'm able to #import them in my -Bridging-Header.h file and immediately access them over in my swift classes.  However, some of my more involved OBJc header files cause a variety of compile errors that have me flummoxed. Please see the image below showing just one of the many variants of issues I encounter in these cases.  Can someone tell me, in general, what things need to be considered when importing OBJc headers into the Bridging-Header file?  Can someone spot the remedy for the error I'm seeing below?

Again - simple .h files are working great.  Only the more involved ones are barfing.

- Phil

[image: image showing error in an OBJc .h file that works fine alone but shows these errors when I include it in my Bridging-Header file.]

Comment: It's probably a matter of order of your imports. You must import those things (i.e. core data) into your objective-c _.m_ file _before_ importing the bridging header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an import. Add the following to your Objective-C Header:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks for that.  Seems odd that the original objc file would not error out on that as well.